# Consistent scroll behavior across browsers

Tags: javascript

I made this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WOrjKG) to simulate the issue.

```js
function createBox() {
  var box = document.createElement("div");
  box.className = "box";
  box.style.backgroundColor = "#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
  
  return box;
}

function prependInnerHTML() {
  console.log('prependInnerHTML'); 
  var element = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var box = createBox();
  element.innerHTML = box.outerHTML + element.innerHTML;
  element.prepend(box);
}

function prependPrepend() {
  console.log('prependPrepend'); 
  var element = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var box = createBox();
  element.prepend(box);
}

function prependPrepend() {
  console.log('prependPrepend'); 
  var element = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var box = createBox();
  element.prepend(box);
}

function prependInsertBefore() {
  console.log('prependInsertBefore'); 
  var element = document.getElementById('scroll');
  var box = createBox();
  element.insertBefore(box, element.firstChild);
}

function scroll() {
  console.log('scroll');
  var detailElement = document.getElementById('details');
  var scrollElement = document.getElementById('scroll');
  
  detailElement.innerHTML = "ScrollTop: " + scrollElement.scrollTop;
}

function clearScrollElement() {
  console.log('clear');
  var element = document.getElementById('scroll');
    while(element.firstChild){
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}
#details {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
#options {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
#scroll {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.box {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
  <span onclick="prependInnerHTML()">InnerHTML</span>
  <span onclick="prependInsertBefore()">InsertBefore</span>
  <span onclick="prependPrepend()">Prepend</span>
  <span onclick="clearScrollElement()">Clear</span>
</div>

<div id="details">
  ScrollTop: 0
</div>

<div id="scroll" onscroll="scroll()"></div>
```

The issue is that when a element gets prepended to a scrollable element, it will have different behaviors across different browsers.

**innerHTML:**

The first prepend method is changing the innerHTML of the scrollable element. This seems to be consistent across multiple browsers.

The problem is that frameworks like Vue don't internally use this method, it probably uses one of the other methods.

**InsertBefore with Chrome:**

If the scrollTop is 0 and we prepend the scrollTop stays zero. If the scrollTop is higher than zero it will adjust the scrollTop to include the height of the prepended element.

**InsertBefore with IE/Edge/Firefox:**

Same behavior as the innerHTML one.

**Prepend:**

Prepend seems te be unsupported on IE/Edge so i'll skip that one.

**Question:**

How do I make the InsertBefore behave the same across all the browsers, without introducing all kinds of browser checks?

Comment: Sounds like chrome's scroll anchoring. I believe it is now on by default since v56. You could try turning it off to see if that normalizes behavior across the browsers and then go from there. You can read a bit about it here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/scroll-anchoring

Comment: @AtheistP3ace This is most likely causing the issue. Looks like I can use the overflow-anchor: none CSS property to resolve the issue.

Comment: sweet! glad you were able to figure it out! good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this

```
/**
 * Adds a new element to the top of the container, If after is a valid element then the new element is added after that element
 * @param {HTMLElement} newItem - newItem to be added
 * @param {HTMLElement} container - container
 * @param {HTMLElement} [after=] - optional parameter, states that the new item will be added after this element
 * @returns {HTMLElement}
 */
function addElementToTop(newItem, container, after) {
    if (after instanceof HTMLElement === false || after.parentElement !== container) {
        var first = container.firstElementChild;
    } else {
        first = after.nextElementSibling;
    }
    if (first !== null) {
        container.insertBefore(newItem, first);
    } else {
        container.appendChild(newItem);
    }
    return newItem;
}
```

Here is the simple version

```
function addElementToTop(newItem, container) {
    var first = container.firstElementChild;
    if (first) container.insertBefore(newItem, first);
    else container.appendChild(newItem);
    return newItem;
}
```

The below version maintains the same view-port but the scroll changes

```
function addElementToTopSteadyScroll(newItem, container) {
    var bot = container.scrollHeight - container.scrollTop;
    var first = container.firstElementChild;
    if (first) container.insertBefore(newItem, first);
    else container.appendChild(newItem);
    container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight - bot;
    return newItem;
}
```

Whereas the below version maintains the same scroll but the view-port changes

```
function addElementToTopFlowScroll(newItem, container) {
    var top = container.scrollTop;
    var first = container.firstElementChild;
    if (first) container.insertBefore(newItem, first);
    else container.appendChild(newItem);
    container.scrollTop = top;
    return newItem;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. It appends instead of prepends? What about the code fixes the scrolling inconsistencies across browsers?

Comment: It's still inconsistent across different browsers.(Tested on Chrome and Edge)

Comment: @Niels Added 2 more functions, please see if any of them suits your needs

Comment: addElementToTopSteadyScroll is inconsistent across different browsers(tested on Edge and Chrome). addElementToTopFlowScroll seems to be consistent across browsers so this could be a possible fix.

Comment: @Niels tested both edge and chrome didn't see  a difference with addElementToTopSteadyScroll, are you sure you used addElementToTopSteadyScroll  and not addElementToTop ?